# How to calculate /refresh the excel file once it is opened and modified by C# code?

Tags: c#, excel, com-interop

I have been using one simple C# console that

- opens one excel file
- modifies the certain ranges on this excel book (which are "inputs")
- refreshes the excel workbook (so that all the formulas using these inputs are refreshed)
- and gets the result on excel as a value

I was able to open and modify the input ranges as intended, but I could not manage to "refresh" (or recalculate if you like) the workbook so that the formulas return me one result with the new inputs.

The following example should make my problem quite clear.

So my question is; how can I refresh one excel application from within C# so that the cells with formulas are refreshed?

Thanks in advance,

Aykut

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;  // reference to excel 12 object library!

namespace deneme
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        /*
        I have a complex formula which was very easy to develop on EXCEL with excel built-in formulas 
        but would have been too complex if I tried to replicate this formula via C# codes. 
        So, I designed this formula on Excel, and designed the C# code to go and get this formula from excel when needed.
        */ 

        // Note 2: his example used the 'Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library' but may be compatible with earlier versions of Interop and other libraries.

        string path = "C:\\FNN\\XLA\\fnnComTemplate.xlsx";

        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
        Excel.Worksheet wSheet = wb.Worksheets[1];

        string HisseKod = "GARAN";
        string bilancoDonem = "2014/09K";
        wSheet.Cells[5, 6].Value = HisseKod;
        wSheet.Cells[5, 7].Value = bilancoDonem;
        xlApp.Calculate();  
        result = wSheet.Cells[5, 11].Value.ToString(); // <<---- THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS! WHATEVER THE CODE RETURN IS NOT THE REFRESHED VALUE!!

        Console.WriteLine( HisseKod + " - " + bilancoDonem + ": " + result);
        wb.Close(true, "fnnComTemplate.xlsx");
        xlApp.Quit();

        Console.ReadLine();


    }

}
```

Comment: You'd have to turn auto-calculate off before it starts to make sense to call Application.Calculate() explicitly.  Since you didn't do that, calling Calculate cannot make any difference and the simplest explanation is that the spreadsheet formulas are borken.

Answer (score 0):

Hans. Thanks for the comment. The problem was that the excel file I open and gather around had certain formulas that used some other addins. And, I realized that I need to open these addins (mostly xla's) together with the main excel file to return the proper results. So,

- the codes are ok and they work as intended.
- But, to get the correct values, not only the main file but all related files (such as addins) should also be opened.

Yes, that should have been the first thing for me to check, but, nevertheless, the case is solved.

Best